# Compiling unsupported module into Linux-based Swift project

Tags: swift, linux, server-side

I need to import the Apple GameController framework for a server-side Swift project running on Linux (where that framework is unsupported).  I do not need the GameController functionality, which used by my code on other platforms - I just need to get my project to compile so I can use the unrelated parts of the code base.

What is the best approach for handling this situation?

Comment: Break your project down into multiple modules, and make them target only the platforms they're needed on (e.g. controller code only targets the client platforms, shared models target all platforms, etc.)

Comment: I have pretty good but imperfect modularity/encapsulation.  Unfortunately, it is one of the most important modules (that wraps GameController) that I really need.  What I ended up doing was create a "stub" class that mimics GameController.  It was a lot of busy work getting all the interfaces setup, but seems to have solved the problem.  Thanks for the suggestion!